# JSON Schema type integer

Tags: jsonschema

In the spec http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html, it only list below types:
null,
boolean,
string,
number,
object,
array.

I know number includes integer, but can I define a "type":"integer" explicitly. I mean will this violate the spec?

Comment: There's an issue on the JSON Schema GitHub page asking exactly this... https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/272

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `{"type": "integer"}` in the schema.

See:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04#section-3.5

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.5.2